# jquery skipping tables that have a specific css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm traversing through the tables using  `$("table").each(function()`

How do I skip the tables that have a css class "**NotThisClass**"

```
$("table").each(function(){
  if( $(this:not('.NotThisClass')))
    {
      // Do Stuff
    }
  }
```

Isn't working, nor is this,

```
if( $(this).not('.NotThisClass'))
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("table").not('.NotThisClass').each(function() {
    //Do your stuff!
});
```

Comment: This looks elegant, i'll give it a go tomorrow. For future reference how might i Do other stuff with '.NotThisClass' rather like a traditional if else statement?

Comment: @Holly - I'm not entirely sure what you're referring to.  The jQuery selectors give you an array of objects to work with.  If there are elements you do not want to work with, it's best to just exclude those right away with your selector so you never iterate over them.  If you need some conditional styling or something else based on the class, then you could have multiple selectors, or while iterating through the objects just use an `if` clause like pankil thakkar pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("table:not(.NotThisClass)").each(function ()
{
  // Do Stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table").each(function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('NotThisClass')))
    {
      // Do Stuff
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried this or something similar before i posted of course i could of  had a typo